# How to extract some information from all of the tables in a library?

Tags: sas

How to PROC SQL to extract information from a library named as **DATA_IN**?

The expected information including:

1. The **name** of the tables.
2. The total **number of variations** contained in the tables.
3. The total **observation number** contained in the tables.

   If the table contains "Subject_ID or Visit_Num", contains mark as 1,
   if not, mark as 0.

I have made attempt like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table table_select as
    select libname, memname, nobs, nvar
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'DATA_IN'
    order by nobs descending
;
```

But still don' t know how to tell if a table contains column "Subject_ID or Visit_Num" and mark it with "1" or "0".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is a *variation* ? Do you mean **variables** instead of **variations** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query that joins `DICTIONARY.TABLES` with `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS`

Example:

```
proc sql;
  create table want (label='sashelp tables with a column named "name" or "MSRP"') as 
  select 
    tables.libname
  , tables.memname
  , tables.nobs
  , tables.nvar
  , not missing(mark.memname) as has_name_or_msrp
  from
    DICTIONARY.TABLES
  left join 
    (select distinct memname from DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
     where columns.libname = 'SASHELP'
       and upcase(columns.name) in ('NAME', 'MSRP')
    ) as mark
  on 
    tables.memname = mark.memname
  where 
    tables.libname = 'SASHELP' 
    and memtype = 'DATA'  /* restrict to only tables */
  order by 
    nobs descending
  ;

  data _null_;
  run;
```